# Mock network call and verify call

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-hooks, jestjs

I am currently working on the testing part of a custom Hook which calls an other custom hook which performs a reactQuery mutation.
I would like to do a test to test my component and I would also like to check that my custom hook is correctly called. but the result is always the same:

- Expected number of calls: 1
- Received number of calls: 0

But in debug mode i can see that the call is really do. Can you help me please ?

This is my custom hook:

```
import useUpdateMove from '../../../../hooks/use-update-move'

const componentWrapper = (id: number) => {
const { update } = useUpdateMove()

const move = () => {
    update(10, {
        onSuccess: () => {
            console.log('success')
        }
    })
}

return { move }
}

export default componentWrapper
```

This is my custom hook that use ReactQuery to do axios call:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import { useMutation } from 'react-query'

import { myApi } from '../../../../../../services'

const useUpdateMove = () => {
const query = async (id: number) => (await myApi.updateCall(id))()
const { mutateAsync } = useMutation(query, {
    onError: () => {
        console.log('error')
    }
})
return { update: mutateAsync }
}

export default useUpdateMove
```

And this is my test

```
describe('myTestWrapper', () => {
const id = 22
it('myTestIt', async () => {
    const updateCallMock = jest.spyOn(myApi, 'updateCall') as jest.SpyInstance

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useComponentWrapper(id))
    result.current.move()

    expect(updateCallMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
})
```

Comment: That's an asynchronous call, but you're not testing for asynchronous behavior.  Additionally it looks to me like this will make a real network call.